# VBA Add-Ins Question

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

I have a problem with a VBA Add-in in Excel 2010.

I've created some code for parsing my excel data. which I made into an Add-in.

However, when I load the Add-in and run, an error occurs.

The error message says: `runtime error 91 object variable or With block variable not set`

The error points to `rowSize = ActiveSheet.Rows.Count`.

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Here is the code,

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim counter As Long
Dim rowSize As Long
Dim userId As String
Dim answers As String
Dim vals As String

Dim i As Integer

rowSize = ActiveSheet.Rows.Count
counter = 1



'Create Column

ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 7).Value = "Country"
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 8).Value = "State"
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 9).Value = "Age"

ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 7).Font.Bold = True
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 8).Font.Bold = True
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 9).Font.Bold = True

ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 7).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 8).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 9).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 7).Borders().LineStyle = xlContinuous
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 8).Borders().LineStyle = xlContinuous
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 9).Borders().LineStyle = xlContinuous

'Set Value
Do While counter < rowSize

If ActiveSheet.Cells(counter, 1).Value = Null Then Exit Do
If ActiveSheet.Cells(counter, 4).Value = "3" Then

    userId = ActiveSheet.Cells(counter, 2).Value
    vals = ActiveSheet.Cells(counter, 6).Value
    'MsgBox (vals)

    temp = Split(vals, ",")
    i = 0

    Do While i < 10
        targetCell = counter + i
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(targetCell, 2).Value = userId Then
           ActiveSheet.Cells(targetCell, 7).Value = temp(0)
           ActiveSheet.Cells(targetCell, 8).Value = temp(1)
           ActiveSheet.Cells(targetCell, 9).Value = temp(2)

           ActiveSheet.Cells(targetCell, 7).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
           ActiveSheet.Cells(targetCell, 8).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
           ActiveSheet.Cells(targetCell, 9).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

           ActiveSheet.Cells(targetCell, 7).Borders().LineStyle = xlContinuous
           ActiveSheet.Cells(targetCell, 8).Borders().LineStyle = xlContinuous
           ActiveSheet.Cells(targetCell, 9).Borders().LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    temp = Null
   'parsing_question_1(vals, userId)
End If

counter = counter + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you have that in the workbook_open event handler?  That will only run when your add-in loads.  Did you want to instead run it on any workbook opened in Excel?  If so, look up "application events".

Comment: I want to run only add-in loads. what event handler I need to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An add-in is just code - no user interface.  Since there's no user interface, there's technically no sheet in the addin file that's the ActiveSheet.  There are actually sheets in an add-in, but none of them can be "active".

If you want to work with worksheet within the add-in, you need to reference those sheets in a different way.  For instance, if you want to work with the first sheet in your add-in, you can use code like

```
Me.Sheets(1).Rows.Count
```

The Me keyword refers to the class you're in.  In this case, you're in the ThisWorkbook module of the add-in, so Me refers the Workbook object that is the add-in.

If you want to work on a particular sheet that's not in your add-in, you can open that workbook in your open event and refer to that sheet.  Such as

```
Dim sh As Worksheet

Set sh = Workbooks.Open("C:\MyPath\MyBook.xls").Sheets(1)

rowSize = sh.Rows.Count
```

Finally, if you want to run code whenever any workbook opens, you have to create a custom class module that listens for application level events.  First create a custom class module call CAppEvents.  In that custom class module, put this code

```
Private WithEvents mApp As Application

Public Property Set App(oApp As Application)
    Set mApp = oApp
End Property

Public Property Get App() As Application
    Set App = mApp
End Property

Private Sub mApp_WorkbookOpen(ByVal wb As Workbook)
    FormatWorkbook wb
End Sub

'or to limit which workbook it runs on - in this example based on the path
'but you may use some other condition like the existence of a particular
'custom document property
Private Sub mApp_WorkbookOpen(ByVal wb As Workbook)
    If wb.Path = "\\Server1\mypath" Then
        FormatWorkbook wb
    End If
End Sub
```

In a standard module, put this code

```
Public clsAppEvents As CAppEvents

Sub Auto_Open()

    Set clsAppEvents = New CAppEvents
    Set clsAppEvents.App = Application

End Sub

Sub FormatWorkbook(wb As Workbook)

    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Set sh = wb.Sheets(1)

    'do stuff here

End Sub
```

Comment: The opening paragraph is not correct: `ActiveSheet` references the currently active sheet (the one with the focus in the GUI), irrespective of what workbokk it is in. The reason the code in the question errors is that when an AddIn Workbook_Open event runs there are no open visible workbooks and hence no ActiveSheet.  If other code in the addin ran later, after another workbook is open and visible, `ActiveSheet` would return a reference to that workbooks active sheet.  (An otherwise good answer, so no down vote)

Comment: I want to run my code when Add-in load, How can I set the event? so, I need firstly open a excel file and run add-in then my code run.

Comment: So I want to run my code only on specific excel file, not all of excel file.

Comment: Thanks @chris neilsen, you're exactly right.  I change the first sentence to fix the misleading part (I hope).

Comment: @user682763 I added another piece of code that limits which workbook it acts on.  Generally you're add-in is loaded and running all the time and listening for the workbook open event.  If a workbook is opened (and optionally meets the conditions) the code is run on that.

Comment: Here's an example of using CustomDocumentProperties  http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/07/16/custom-document-properties/  I usually have my add-in load when I start Excel, then check for the existence of CDPs to determine if I want my code to act on the workbook that is opened.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `Woorkbook_Open` event of the addin runs before the first visible sheet opens, there is no active sheet at that point in time, therefore `ActiveSheet` is not set

As Tim said, you probably don't want this code in the addin _Open event anyway

[Heres a link that shows how to do Application Events](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx)